# Service to carry bags to / from airport in Australia - right up to checkin?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, australia

I've got a flight in a week to Melbourne. However, I've recently had surgery and am not allowed to lift anything heavier than 2kg (4.5lb).

The trick being that I need to take a suit and carry-on bag.  I could check it all, but I still need to get it to the airport in Sydney, and from the airport to my accommodation in Melbourne.

Are there services that would carry all my bags for me right up to the check-in counter? I'd ask friends but it's during work hours. The train + skybus fares for them would also add up, to the extent it's worth enquiring about a service.

Comment: Have you considered a parcel courier service instead?  Eg. Fastway charges just ~$15 for a 10kg box from Sydney to Melbourne, and your employer is likely a customer of this or some other courier already.

Comment: @jpatokal it's a personal trip, not business (suit is for wedding). Not a bad idea though...I could courier clothes to the hotel...

Comment: Are you able to push a luggage cart?  If you take a taxi or shuttle to the airport, the driver would probably be willing to unload and put them on a cart for you (especially if you tip a little extra).  And at baggage claim, if you ask nicely, some kindly stranger may help you put your bags on the cart so you can get them to your taxi outside.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'll have to check with the doctor, good thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hire a car service, the driver will usually be able to assist you door to door (with a suitable tip, of course).

The advantage to a hired car is that the driver will be able to park it in the garage and help you with the luggage from your living room right up to the airline counter -- whereas a taxi driver will be loathe to leave their ride.

Car services are popularly thought to be the province of the super-rich but if you price them out, they are actually not too extravagant, especially given the circumstances here.  When you call the dispatch (reservations center), tell them about your medical condition and ask them if they can get you a driver who won't mind helping you with your luggage.

Answer (score 5):

Should you really wish to fly along with your with luggage, in my opinion you should qualify as a passenger needing special assistance. You could therefore contact your airline in advance and ask them for help carrying your luggage within the terminal building. That's what I did when I had to fly with a broken leg, crutches and a cask.

When it comes to getting to/from your accommodation, I can imagine your taxi driver will be glad to help you out. Don't forget to tip, of course.

A somewhat more effortless solution, as @jpatokal suggested, would be having a shipping company mail you your belongings to/from wherever you're going. Send them at least 24h before you get to Melbourne and you should be good.